# How do I ignore timezone when parsing using moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I need to read date from js `Date` object as if it was in UTC, however the object contains timezone.

How do I create `moment` object as if it was in UTC when it has some Timezone data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can do this by using  `moment.utc().`

   ```
   moment([2011, 10, 8, 5]).format(); 

   moment.utc([2011, 10, 8, 5]).format();
   ```
2. If you want your timezone completely ignored, you can use this code.

   ```
     var firstDayStr = '29 January 2014';
     var startAtTime = '10:01:02 AM';
     var localFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss';
     var m = moment(firstDayStr + ' ' + startAtTime).format(localFormat);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UTC mode of moment.js

> [UTC](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/)
>
> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.
> If you want to parse or display a moment in UTC, you can use `moment.utc()` instead of `moment()`.

```js
var date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York"})
var now = moment().format('MMM DD h:mm A');
var nowUTC = moment.utc().format('MMM DD h:mm A');
console.log(now);
console.log(nowUTC);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```